# 'Module parse failed: Unexpected token' when adding css file to React App

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

This error pops up in the browser right after importing the css file to the index.js.  I've tried inputting different style loaders into the webpack.config.js file but to no success.  Here is the css:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

I've imported with:

```
import './App.css'
```

and here is the webpack file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html') })]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Webpack config currently does not include any rules on how to compile CSS files. You can configure Webpack to do so in the following way:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

so in your specific example it would be something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html') })]
};
```

For more details about style-loader, please visit their [documentation.](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/)

Comment: Man, I've tried that and unfortunately still get the same response.  I've followed the steps in the link you've sent as well.  Thanks for getting back to me

Comment: Do you still receive the same error message?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do

Comment: If you could please create a codesandbox with your current code, then I can take a look at it in more detail to reproduce it.